# Internet detection on cordova 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, cordova

I was using phonegap 2.5.0 and just migrated to cordova 5.1.1. In 2.5.0 i used the below script to check for internet connection

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])

        $('#notification').fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $("#notification").fadeOut(7000);
        });



    }

    </script>
```

But when i migrated to 5.1.1 the script fails to work. Though i have replace   `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>`to  `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`and i have cordova.js in my root folder which is the www

Comment: Do you have the `network-connection` plugin installed?

Comment: I suggest to create a clean new project and copy the /www/ files in right place, add platforms, plugins and compile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the plugin for that, please read: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

To add the plugin, use:

```
cordova plugin add nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
```